# What does "stack;" on a line by itself as used in the LVM2 source code mean in C?

Tags: c

What does the statement:

```
        stack;
```

on a line by itself, as used in the LVM2 source code mean? https://www.sourceware.org/lvm2/

```
        if (!_mountinfo_parse_line(buffer, &maj, &min, target) ||
            !read_fn(buffer, maj, min, target, cb_data)) {
                stack;
                r = 0;
                break;
        }
```

I see that in gdb the statement "stack;" is compiled to:

```
lea    r8,[rip+0x936db]        # 0xdd704
lea    rsi,[rip+0xa2f5d]        # 0xecf8d
xor    ecx,ecx
mov    edx,0xb37
mov    edi,0x7
xor    eax,eax
call   0x80950 <print_log>
```

I also noticed that I cannot assign the results to a variable:

error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Cannot be called as stack() or given arguments as in e.g. stack(0):

error: called object is not a function or function pointer

I also tried to grep through the source code for "stack" to see how it is derived or defined, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: How do you compile it? Please provide the full command line.

Comment: What *is* `stack`? What is it declared or defined as? Is it a macro? A variable? Something else?

Comment: More generally speaking, any expression can be used as a statement using the statement terminator `;`. That's how, for example, simple functions calls works, it's a function call expression followed by a statement terminator which turns the expression into a statement.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: No, it's not a function call (unless `stack` is a macro that expands to a function call). A function call requires parentheses -- empty parentheses if no arguments are passed: `stack();`. UPDATE: After reading the answers, it turns out `stack` *is* a macro that expands to a function call. IMHO it would have been clear if it had been defined as a function-like macro, so calls could be written more clearly as `stack();`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it for you. It's a macro at lib\log\log.h.

Line 90 - `#define stack log_debug("<backtrace>")   /* Backtrace on error */`

Answer (score 4):

It's a debug print statement.

After a little bit of searching:

```
#define stack log_debug("<backtrace>")  /* Backtrace on error */

#define log_debug(x...) LOG_LINE(_LOG_DEBUG, x)

#define LOG_LINE(l, x...) \
    print_log(l, __FILE__, __LINE__ , 0, ## x)
```

Sort of just calls the `print_log` function with the string `"<backtrace>"` as an argument. This function then prints the argument and the file name and current line, along with a little extra stuff.